# Parameterized interfaces in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm building a Kotlin microservice that processes events of various types and publishes them out to external partner systems. I have all of the event classes implementing a common interface called `GenericPartnerEvent`:

```
interface GenericPartnerEvent

data class EventTypeOne(
    val key: String,
    val payload: String
) : GenericPartnerEvent
```

I then have a series of event handler classes, one per external partner, that are defined like this:

```
interface PartnerEventHandler<in T : GenericPartnerEvent> {
    fun handleEvent(event: T)
}

class PartnerOneEventTypeOneHandler : PartnerEventHandler<EventTypeOne> {
  ...
}
```

I want a generic way to fetch the event handler class of the correct type given a partner and event type; something like:

```
fun getEventHandler(partner: String, eventType: String): PartnerEventHandler<GenericPartnerEvent> {
  if (...something...) return PartnerOneEventTypeOneHandler()
}
```

But what I inevitably get is something like:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: PartnerEventHandler<GenericPartnerEvent>
Found: PartnerOneEventTypeOneHandler
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since your PartnerEventHandler type is contravariant (`in`), a subtype's type cannot be upcast. A `PartnerEventHandler<EventTypeOne>` cannot accept any subtype of `GenericPartnerEvent` as an input, so a `PartnerEventHandler<EventTypeOne>` is not a subtype of `PartnerEventHandler<GenericPartnerEvent>`.

Since you retrieve handlers using a String representation of the type, I don't see how generics buy you anything here anyway. The `handle` function might as well take an input type of Any and reject incorrect types with an exception or by returning null or something.

Comment: Thanks! I spent a fair amount of time with the Kotlin documentation on generics and found it to be pretty impenetrable in some places (likely more my fault than theirs), so thanks for the concise explanation.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this approach seems to pass muster with the compiler:

```
inline fun <reified T : GenericPartnerEvent> getHandlerForPartner(partner: String): PartnerEventHandler<T>? {
    return when (partner) {
        "partner-one" -> when (T::class) {
            EventTypeOne::class -> PartnerOneEventTypeOneHandler() as PartnerEventHandler<T>
            EventTypeTwo::class -> PartnerOneEventTypeTwoHandler() as PartnerEventHandler<T>
            else -> null
        }
        "partner-two" -> when (T::class) {
            EventTypeOne::class -> PartnerTwoEventTypeOneHandler() as PartnerEventHandler<T>
            EventTypeTwo::class -> PartnerTwoEventTypeTwoHandler() as PartnerEventHandler<T>
            else -> null
        }
        else -> null
    }
}
```

It does give me a warning: `Unchecked cast: PartnerOneEventTypeOneHandler to PartnerEventHandler<T>`. So I guess we'll see what happens at runtime.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid way to do it if it's acceptable for the function to require you to know the type at compile time. The OP's code only has a String representation of the type.